# How i center this background photo

Tags: css, styles

```
body {

  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url(111.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}
```

hello guys. i have a problem. i have this little image on background 111.png is a simple image with 300 x 300 and with this code is put on left upper.

Can you show me guys how i transform this css style code to put the image background to the center?
thanks.

Comment: `background-position`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `background-position: center;`